# Is it possible to train a linear classifier to maximize f1-score?

Tags: classification, linear

The usual approach to maximise f1-score in a classification problem is to train the classifier first and then optimize a threshold value on a validation set. The decoupling of weight learning and threshold searching sounds sub-optimal to me. Is there anyway to learn both at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

In theory you an optimize any objective function. F1-score however does not lead to a convex optimization problem that can be solved via gradient descent, means finding the exact optimal weights and thresholds is intractable in the general case. Approximatively it can be optimized using numerical optimization methods, with the risk to end up only in a local maximum, which is again suboptimal. This may be the reason for the usual approach you described, which is faster and more stable.